# How to use VisualStudio macro in pre-test script?

Tags: powershell, build-process

I am using VS2013. I am running a build definition based on the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml build template on a local build server. I am trying to pass the value of a Visual Studio macro to a pre-test PowerShell 3.0 script.

My script currently only logs the value passed. It looks like

```
Param(
 [string]$MyParam
)
$MyParam | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\ProgramData\Company\PS.log' -Append
```

The Pre-test script arguments field contains
**-MyParam $(ProjectDir)**
I expected the ProjectDir macro would be translated to the actual directory, but the literal string **$(ProjectDir)** is logged.

My question is: how can I use the value of the VS macro variables in my pre-test script?

Thanks, PC

Comment: Try -MyParam '$(ProjectDir)'.

Comment: Making this change causes '$(ProjectDir)' to be logged--that is, including the single-quotes.  FWIW, I don't believe this is a PowerShell issue, it's a TFS Process template issue.  I need to get TFS Build to expand the $(ProjectDir) (e.g.) variable before passing the value down to the script.  I don't think it's even possible for PS to expand this variable; I've logged the env: variables, and none of the build macros/variables appear.